# Angular JS : Show/Close div based on select option without using controller or model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I want to show/hide div based on select option but without using controller or model.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<select class="">
                                                    <option class="add_btn_with_file">Add button with file</option>
                                                    <option class="add_btn_with_link">Add button with link</option>
                                                    <option class="add_btn_with_text">Add button with text </option>
                                                </select>


<div class="">

                                                <input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" class="file_display_none" />
                                               
                                            </div>


<div class="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="button with link" ></div>
```

what i want is .

when i select **button with file** then **file** div should be open and others should be closed and when i select **button with link** then **textbox** should open.

I can do using controller and model, but I want to do it without using them.

so is there any way so that I can do that?

Thank You.

Comment: It is not possible, you just have to use it, because the ng-model watches for the changes for you

Comment: okay so ng-model keeps the state of changing value based on select option.. right?

Comment: try ng-switch.... http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-switch

Comment: you can avoid controller but surely you will need ng-model else there is no context in saying you are using angular and dont wanna use controller or model

Comment: yes @Rishi , else when the item changes it wont update the variable with the new value

Comment: Coming in to second Vinod Louis-- you can get away with avoiding the controller but the model is the "2" in "2-way data binding" (the "1" being the view)-- it's the basis for one of the main appeals of the angular framework.  Why exactly are you trying to avoid using the controller and model?

Comment: i have been told to do without using if possible. otherwise have to use controller. that's why

Comment: @Rishi Post the css as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comments I find you don't want to use Controller or model to do your task. I wonder why use angular then!!

Anyways, you must understand that model and Controller are correlated. Go through [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts), it will clarify a lot of things for you.

However, if you don't want to write the logic in controller, you can go ahead with a combination of `ng-model` and `ng-switch` as follows,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<select class="" ng-model="fileSelect">
                                                    <option class="add_btn_with_file" value="file">Add button with file</option>
                                                    <option class="add_btn_with_link" value="link">Add button with link</option>
                                                    <option class="add_btn_with_text" value="text">Add button with text </option>
                                                </select>

<div ng-switch="fileSelect">
<div class="" ng-switch-when="file">

                                                <input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" class="file_display_none" />
                                               
                                            </div>


<div class="" ng-switch-when="text">
  <input type="text" placeholder="button with link" ></div>

<div class="" ng-switch-default>

                                                <input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" class="file_display_none" />
                                               
                                            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working. by default  **add button with file** should be there and others should be hidden and based on selection, from select value , related div should be displayed.

Comment: Modifying my answer!!

Comment: still not working. i want only file type input to be displayed by default and others to be hidden and when i select button with link then only text box with link placeholder should be opened.

Comment: @Rishi are you running the code here on stackoverflow?? Or in your local setup? If you are running it from here.. it won't work because you haven't included the css file which hides and shows the divs.

Comment: not exactly.. when i select button with file then it doesn't show  **input file** div

Comment: @Rishi Can you post your CSS.. Could be a problem there

Comment: yes.. done.. i have done using **ng-init** and **ng-show**. it worked for me.

Comment: @Rishi just a quick thing, yes you can do with `ng-init` and `ng-show` for two such fields.. `ng-switch` can help you with multiple such items/items/conditions

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, sure, it's a trivial piece of jQuery. Demonstrated here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zojPKa, but the basis is just a change() and a switch.

```
$("select.foo").change(function(){
  var selected = $("select.foo").val();
  switch(selected){
    case "Add button with file":
      $("#fileInput").show();
      $("#textInput").hide();
      break;
    case "Add button with text":
      $("#fileInput").hide();
      $("#textInput").show();
      break;
    default:
      $("#fileInput, #textInput").hide();
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: i don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: @Rishi Well, if you don't want to use the controller, model, or jQuery, you can probably work out how to do the above in vanilla JS. I will leave that to you.